# Words for Numbers

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I'm trying to solve this:
https://open.kattis.com/problems/wordsfornumbers

What is the problem of this code?

```
import re
import sys


ls = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
ls2 = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

mp = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'tree', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven',
      8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten', 11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen', 14: 'fourteen',
      15: 'fifteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen', 18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty',
      30: 'thirty', 40: 'forty', 50: 'fifty', 60: 'sixty', 70: 'seventy', 80: 'eighty', 90: 'ninety'}

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(9):
        mp[(i+2) * 10 + (j+1)] = ls2[i] + '-' + ls[j]


for line in sys.stdin:
    if re.findall(r'^\d+((?= )|$)', line):
        s = re.sub(r'((?<= )|^)\d+((?= )|$)', lambda m: mp[int(m.group())], line).capitalize()
    else:
        s = re.sub(r'((?<= )|^)\d+((?= )|$)', lambda m: mp[int(m.group())], line)
    print(s, end='')
```

Comment: The capitalize needs to be used only when number is at beginning. use `re.sub` two times, one searches at beginning of sentence, and the other in rest of the sentence.

Comment: I test it. but don't work still.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
s = re.sub(r'([^\S\r\n]|^)(\d+)(?!\S)', repl, line,flags=re.M)
```

The replacement argument is a callback method that build the right replacement based on the text captured in Group 1:

```
def repl(m):
    if len(m.group(1)) > 0:
        return "{}{}".format(m.group(1),mp[int(m.group(2))]) 
    else:
        return "{}{}".format(m.group(1), mp[int(m.group(2))]).capitalize()
```

As you see, the regex matches like this:

- `([^\S\r\n]|^)` - Group 1: either a horizontal whitespace or start of a line (due to `re.M` flag, `^` matches start of line positions, too)
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: any 1 or more digits
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary (immediately to the right of the current location, there must be a space or end of string).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fHtYIe).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
the problem was 'tree' 
that should be 'three